# SCCM uninstalled on clients in organization

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

In my organization a project has begun to install SCCM on every computer. My job is to filter out computers which do not have SCCM installed on them (that part is done), find out why and try to install.

Unfortunately, I’m inexperienced with SCCM logs and find it hard to locate the problems (if there are any) and there is a huge number of devices I have to check all by myself and accessing each computer’s C$ will take years.
The OS of the problematic computers are Windows 10/7/XP/Server 2016.
Can anyone help me with these issues please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd start by referring to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/clients/deploy/deploy-clients-to-windows-computers) and deciding whether you need to take a different approach to the client push, if that is what you had problems with. There could be a number of reasons why it has failed. I'd suggest showing people here what you have tried doing already to check the [client logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/hierarchy/log-files#BKMK_ClientInstallLog).

Comment: You can also check the [Server Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/sudheesn/troubleshooting-sccm-part-i-client-push-installation)

Answer (score 0):

The client install logs on the local machine are here C:\Windows\ccmsetup\Logs.  You could script something to pull the logs and dump on a network share.

You can pull the CMTrace.exe from the server install directory to read the logs.

They are most likely failing for the same reason, I would start with looking at the firewall and make sure WinRM is enabled.

There are 3 methods to installing the agent GPO, Login Script, or from the console.